# ArrayList Java String remove doesnt delete

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am working with Arraylist of objects.
while i already succeeded in delete values from Arraylist while they are numeral.

i'm having trouble delete from arraylist while they are String 
here is the example :

```
public class ArrayListDemo {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

    // create an empty array list with an initial capacity
    ArrayList<Namer> arrlist = new ArrayList<Namer>( );

    // use add() method to add values in the list
    arrlist.add(new Namer("1","A","G"));
    arrlist.add(new Namer("2","E","G"));
    arrlist.add(new Namer("3","F","G"));

    System.out.println("Size of list: " + arrlist.size());

    // let us print all the values available in list
    for (Namer value : arrlist) {
      System.out.println("age = " + value.age);
     }  

    arrlist.remove("3");

    System.out.println("Now, Size of list: " + arrlist.size());

     for (Namer value : arrlist) {
      System.out.println("age = " + value.age); //System.out.println("Value = " + value);
    }  
  }
}
```

and the result of running it proof it doesnt deleted the spesific row
i need to delete if with String and cant use number as "Key" .

```
Size of list: 3
age = 1
age = 2
age = 3

Now, Size of list: 3
age = 1
age = 2
age = 3
```

what can i make it to work with String in order to delete ?

if that's help

this is the object of arrayList

```
public class Namer
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    public String age;
    public String name;

    public String L_name;


    public Namer(String a, String na , String Lname)
    {
        // initialise instance variables
         age =a;
         name=na;
         L_name=Lname;
   }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the object or the index to remove and you are not using either ...
Try this code :

```
arrlist.remove(2);
```

or

```
// create an empty array list with an initial capacity
ArrayList<Namer> arrlist = new ArrayList<Namer>( );

Namer namer1= new Namer("1","A","G");
Namer namer2= new Namer("2","E","G");
Namer namer3= new Namer("3","F","G");

// use add() method to add values in the list
arrlist.add(namer1);
arrlist.add(namer2);
arrlist.add(namer3);

arrlist.remove(namer3);
```

Answer (score 6):

You have `Namer` objects in your `ArrayList`, not `String`s.  When you call `remove("3")`, the `ArrayList` will look for an object that returns `true` when `equals` is called on it with `"3"`.  Of course, no `String` will compare `equals` with any `Namer`.

You must do the comparison yourself with the `name` field, and remove the appropriate item.  This can be done with an `Iterator` and its `remove` method.

Comment: please tell me, am i suppsed to create new method called equals ?
im my class Namer ?

and where do i call this method equals ?

Comment: No, just call `equals` on the `name` attribute, a `String`.

Comment: i am sorry but could you be more specific please ?

Answer (score 0):

The method `arrlist.remove(idx)` takes as paramenter the (interger) index of the element to be removed from the array. There's no such thing as a "key" for `ArrayLists`.

You probably want to use `java.util.Map<Integer,Namer>`.

Comment: The OP is intending to use the overload that takes an Object parameter: [public boolean remove(Object o)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove(java.lang.Object))